# WordPress custom loop filter by meta_key and value with serialize data

Tags: wordpress, meta-key

I am trying to run custom loop for Custom Post Type with filtering by some `meta_key` and `value`

Now simple meta value works fine but here I have a challenge with the below kind of serialized data (nested).

I am using [wpalchemy](https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy) for meta box. `meta_key` for the post type is `_event_meta` and `value` is as below

```
a:9:{s:19:"ac_event_operations";a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Training";}s:18:"ac_event_positions";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"Supervisor";}s:18:"ac_event_employees";a:1:{i:0;s:2:"15";}s:13:"ac_event_date";s:10:"2017-06-15";s:19:"ac_event_start_time";s:5:"06:30";s:17:"ac_event_end_time";s:5:"07:00";s:14:"ac_event_place";s:6:"Office";s:18:"ac_event_organizer";s:4:"Jack";s:16:"ac_event_contact";s:4:"Rose";}
```

I am trying to filter `All Events` based on `ac_event_operations`, `ac_event_positions`, `ac_event_employees`

So for me, the challenge is to get events filtering with the value from above meta_keys. Here is the query I used but of course, it is not giving any result.

```
global $event_mb;
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $event_mb->get_the_id(), TRUE );

$paged    = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args     = [
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'meta_query'     => [
        'meta_key' => '_event_meta',
        'value'    => '%ac_event_employees%',
        'compare'  => 'LIKE'
    ],

];
$temp     = $wp_query;
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like below,

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'country',
                'value'   => 'Israel',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'age',
                'value'   => array( 20, 30 ),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            )
    )
 );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

For more Ref : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Comment: I want to fetch value dynamically rather than statically defined in the array. I have a little doubt on the solution you have provided.

Comment: You can use just meta_key and value in loop. I just add for example, you can modify as like you want.